# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.1.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

After update all packages in solution to version 1.1.1 while running solutiong i experienced this error:
Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.1.0.0
This solution doesn't work for me
      true
  true

Could anyone help me with fixing this?

Comment: Did you try a clean/rebuild?

Comment: yes, this doesn't work for me. Also tried to delete bin and obj folder, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

did you try to remove and add the reference?

Also please have a look in csproj.
It can be a possibility that you specify the version there. Example:
  `<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>`